# Set Directories for Silent Install

Tags: installshield

I've created a Basic MSI project and have a fully functional installer. Some directories need path values found in the registry. I have a few "Set Directory" custom actions to handle this for me. The regular GUI installer works just fine, but the silent install doesn't seem to run any of the "Set Directory" custom actions. What do I need to do to make these custom actions set my directory properties correctly?

Any help would be appreciated. Here is an example of one such custom action:

```
Directory Name:       DIRECTORYNAME
Directory Value:      [REGISTRYPATH]\subpath
Execution Scheduling: Always execute
Install UI Sequence:  After PathWelcome
Install Condition:    [REGISTRYPATH]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule your custom actions in both InstallUISequence and InstallExecuteSequence. Silent installs use only InstallExecuteSequence.

Comment: Also read the following for advanced considerations to take into account. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/blair-symes-recently-posted-building-32.html

Answer (score 1):

Type 35 Custom Actions ( Set Directory ) must come after CostFinalize.  If you need it before CostFinalize use Type 51 ( Set Property ) Custom Actions.  I don't know what PathWelcome is so I can't tell you which to use.

Also read the following for advanced considerations to take into account.

http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/blair-symes-recently-posted-building-32.html